# modal of AngularJS + d3 - open() str argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I would like to send both string and integer arguments to AngularJS modal form (BootstrapUI) by use of the D3 .attr():

```
.attr("ng-click", "open(" + node.name + "," + node.id + ")" )
```

The code above works fine but only when both variables are integer type, i.e.

```
.attr("ng-click", "open(" + node.id + "," + node.id + ")" )
```

One has to work differently with str variables?

PS. node.name is not empty, I'm using it in other places of the code

Down below I put some more code.

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('plunker').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.open = function (nodeName, nodeId) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'MainInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {

     nodeName: function() {
     return nodeName;
   },
   
   nodeId: function() {
     return nodeId;
   },

      }
    });

  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };

});

angular.module('plunker').controller('MainInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, nodeName, nodeId) {

  $scope.nodeName = nodeName;
  $scope.nodeId = nodeId;
  
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

});
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

...

<div class="modal-body">

{{nodeName}}, {{nodeId}}

</div>

...

</script>
```

Best!,
kami

Comment: Are you saying that the second doesn't work? In what way?

Comment: output of the first code sample: ,1 output of the second code sample: 1,1; but node.name is not empty :/

Comment: Hmm, looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Have you tried adding `$timeout(function (){$scope.apply();},0)` to the end of the function

Comment: Which one? I've never used timeout().

Comment: Try adding that line to the end of `$scope.open()`

Comment: to cjds: nope:/ not working, but thank You for tip and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o.k. I've found a solution, problem was with arg of the d3's .attr():

```
.attr("ng-click", "open(" + "'" + node.type + "'" + "," + node.id + ")" )
```

thank You all for tips and time!